# Django using email authentication with djoser for login

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

So i tried using djoser recently and i want to use email instead of username to login.

Djoser : http://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Then i try to customise the token create/login to change from username to email in the serializers.py

Original

```
class TokenCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
password = serializers.CharField(
    required=False, style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )

    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid_credentials': constants.INVALID_CREDENTIALS_ERROR,
        'inactive_account': constants.INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TokenCreateSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.user = None
    self.fields[User.USERNAME_FIELD] = serializers.CharField(
        required=False
    )

def validate(self, attrs):
    self.user = authenticate(
        username=attrs.get(User.USERNAME_FIELD),
        password=attrs.get('password')
        )

        self._validate_user_exists(self.user)
        self._validate_user_is_active(self.user)
        return attrs

    def _validate_user_exists(self, user):
        if not user:
            self.fail('invalid_credentials')

    def _validate_user_is_active(self, user):
        if not user.is_active:
            self.fail('inactive_account')
```

Edited

```
class TokenCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
password = serializers.CharField(
    required=False, style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )

    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid_credentials': constants.INVALID_CREDENTIALS_ERROR,
        'inactive_account': constants.INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TokenCreateSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.user = None
    self.fields[User.EMAIL_FIELD] = serializers.EmailField(
        required=False
    )

def validate(self, attrs):
    self.user = authenticate(
        email=attrs.get(User.EMAIL_FIELD),
        password=attrs.get('password')
        )

        self._validate_user_exists(self.user)
        self._validate_user_is_active(self.user)
        return attrs

    def _validate_user_exists(self, user):
        if not user:
            self.fail('invalid_credentials')

    def _validate_user_is_active(self, user):
        if not user.is_active:
            self.fail('inactive_account')
```

but the result i get in the api is this

```
{
"non_field_errors": [
    "Unable to login with provided credentials."
]
```

I did try other method but all have same result. Is there a way to make it using of email to authenticate instead of username ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Djoser` uses `authenticate` method from `django.contrib.auth`. By default the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` is set to use`django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` which will try to get the user model using default manager `get_by_natural_key` method, which does:

```
def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
```

You can check the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py) for this.

My approach on this was to enhance django's `UserManager`, assuming your `User` model is subclass of `AbstractUser`, by trying to get the user by email or username, like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager
from django.db.models import Q

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):

    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        return self.get(
            Q(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username}) |
            Q(**{self.model.EMAIL_FIELD: username})
        )
```

Use that in your `User` model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

You should now be able to login using email or username

Answer (score 12):

I was looking for the answer to this question and came across this thread!

Everything works, but then I found an even simpler solution:

```
DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email'
}
```

I don’t know, maybe someone will need it!

Answer (score 2):

I realized it in this way

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers

from djoser.compat import get_user_email_field_name
from djoser.conf import settings


User = get_user_model()


class TokenCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(required=False, style={"input_type": "password"})

    default_error_messages = {
        "invalid_credentials": settings.CONSTANTS.messages.INVALID_CREDENTIALS_ERROR,
        "inactive_account": settings.CONSTANTS.messages.INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = None

        self.email_field = get_user_email_field_name(User)
        self.fields[self.email_field] = serializers.EmailField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        password = attrs.get("password")
        email = attrs.get("email")
        self.user = authenticate(
            request=self.context.get("request"), email=email, password=password
        )
        if not self.user:
            self.user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
            if self.user and not self.user.check_password(password):
                self.fail("invalid_credentials")
        if self.user and self.user.is_active:
            return attrs
        self.fail("invalid_credentials")
```