# Login by either email or username in Djoser (JWT authentication)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am working Django rest framework with djoser.

I want to login by either email or username in Djoser(JWT). Can you please give me solution for that? (I am using custom user model)

Answer will be appreciate.

Comment: See this [Django using email authentication with djoser for login](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47197369/9914466) Just override `authenticate` method.

Answer (score 0):

**My Simple Method to do Job Done:**

**I'm using:**

```
Django==3.2.9
djangorestframework==3.12.4
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.0.0
```

I have my custom Users Model for more customization according to my requirement

In my custom User model, I defined Email address as the default username field. like as below:
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

**My Settings:**

```
in setting.py file

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
    ...
}


in Urls.py file

urlpatterns = [
    path('token', MyObtainTokenPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    # in my case this token route is the login route
]
```

Now I have my Custom Login View named as MyObtainTokenPairView and it has the following code:

```
from .serializers import MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView


class MyObtainTokenPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

For the serialization purpose, I use my default Serializer Class which overrides the **TokenObtainPairSerializer** class of rest_framework_simplejwt serializers class methods are as follows:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework import exceptions

from users.models import Users
from utilities.dataValidation import validateEmail


class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        token['user_name'] = user.user_name
        token['email'] = user.email

        return token

    def validate(self, attrs):
        userName = attrs.get("email")
        password = attrs.get("password")

        # print("attrs values: ", attrs)

        if validateEmail(userName) is False:
            try:
                user = Users.objects.get(user_name=userName)
                if user.check_password(password):
                    attrs['email'] = user.email
         
                """
                 In my case, I used the Email address as the default Username 
                 field in my custom User model. so that I get the user email 
                 from the Users model and set it to the attrs field. You can 
                 be modified as your setting and your requirement 
                """

            except Users.DoesNotExist:
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
                    'No such user with provided credentials'.title()) 
        
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        return data
```

To check email is valid or not I use one function as follows:

```
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


def validateEmail(email):
    try:
        validate_email(email)
        return True
    except ValidationError:
        return False
```

All this work done I'm able to do login user either using email and or UserName of the user.